# How to optimize switch case in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, switch-statement

I have a view to show different styles according to parameters passed in.

There are more than 50 different styles, each style have a conflict layout. I want to show different styles according to the style passed in.

I have to write 50+ cases as below:

```
struct StyleDefaultView: View {
    let style: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("111")
        }
        
    }
}

struct Style1View: View {
    let style: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            VStack() {
                Text("111")
            }
            Text("222")
        }
    }
}

struct Style2View: View {
    let style: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("111")
            HStack() {
                Text("111")
                Text("111")
            }
        }
        Text("222")
    }
}

struct Style3View: View {
    let style: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text("111")
            VStack() {
                Text("111")
                Text("111")
            }
        }
        Text("222")
    }
}

struct Style4View: View {
    let style: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text("222")
            VStack() {
                Text("111")
                Text("111")
            }
            Text("111")
        }
    }
}

// ... other 50+ style

struct ContentView: View {
    let style: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            switch style {
            case 1:
                Style1View(style: style)
            case 2:
                Style2View(style: style)
            case 3:
                Style3View(style: style)
            case 4:
                Style4View(style: style)
            // case .. other 50+ style
            default:
                StyleDefaultView(style: style)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify these swift case codes? Similar to the reflection in Java as code bellow

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let style: Int
    let viewMap = [
        0 : "StyleDefaultView",
        1 : "Style1View",
        2 : "Style2View",
        3 : "Style3View",
        // ... other 50 views
    ]
    var body: some View {
        let viewName: String = viewMap[style] ?? "StyleDefaultView"
        //  initialization a view by a string 
        viewName(style : style)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is 2 or 3 possible ways to refactor your codes, First you can use ForEach on StyleViews, second you can use Array in each StyleView as well, third you can use dic for all Style. If you do those 3 steps, may you do not need Switch, and may you just init a View.

Comment: Why do you have so many `View`s to begin with? Is there a pattern that they follow?

Comment: Is there any way to use variable to call a struct?
Such as 
`
let styleViewName: String = "Style3View"
styleViewName(style: style)
`

Comment: I have many diffrent style view, and the style and code of these views have big difference.

Comment: @mars: Use a dic and you do not need that long Switch. That is the right way I said. You are going to work with optional View!

Comment: @swiftPunk Thanks for your answer, but my styleview is very conflict, not only simle Text. 
How to use dic for all style?
Is there any way to use variable to call a struct? Such as ` let styleViewName: String = "Style3View" styleViewName(style: style) `

Comment: I suggest you checking on [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery), you'll be able to add annotations for all your styles and generate switch based on this annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

this is just an example to get you thinking about looping over your different style views:

```
struct StyleDefaultView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("111")
        }
    }
}

struct Style1View: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            VStack() {
                Text("111")
            }
            Text("222")
        }
    }
}

struct Style2View: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("111")
            HStack() {
                Text("111")
                Text("111")
            }
        }
        Text("222")
    }
}
struct Style3View: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("1112")
        Text("1112")
        Text("1112")
    }
}

struct Style4View: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("1112")
        Text("1")
    }
}

class StyleViewModel {
    let styles: [AnyView] = [
        AnyView(Style1View()),
        AnyView(Style2View()),
        AnyView(Style3View()),
        AnyView(Style4View())]
    
    func selectedStyleView(_ ndx: Int) -> AnyView {
        if ndx < styles.count {
            return styles[ndx]
        } else {
            return AnyView(StyleDefaultView())
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let styles = StyleViewModel()
    let style: Int = 2

    var body: some View {
        styles.selectedStyleView(style)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my styleview is very conflict, not only simle Text.

Comment: I see, what you are showing us is not what you want

Comment: Yes, I use a lot Text just want to show this subview have different conflict layout.

Comment: updated my answer with another possibility to show your 50 different style views in a loop, without the switch.

Comment: @workingdog: you can bring that long array out of struct as well, no need making private or creating with view.

Comment: @workingdog styles: [AnyView] will create all styleview at first , which will consume a lot of resources and affect performance. Is it?

Comment: @mars: That is true! it will bring your app to knee if you use that array, use dic instead much lighter.

Comment: @workingdog: Instead of typing `AnyView` for each View, `let arrayOfAnyView: [AnyView] = [Style1View(), Style2View(), Style3View(), ... , Style50View()].map({ view in AnyView(view) })`

Comment: @swiftPunk  `let arrayOfAnyView: [AnyView] = [Style1View(), Style2View(), Style3View(), ... , Style50View()].map({ view in AnyView(view) })` Whether will be initialized beforehand and consume a lot of cpu resources?

Comment: good, my answer/example got you thinking about looping over your different style views. All good points by @swiftPunk and yourself.

Comment: @swiftPunk  I edit the question, is there a way to initialize a structure with a string variable?

Comment: @workingdog I edit the question, is there a way to initialize a structure with a string variable?

Comment: I've updated my answer, and tested your theory that it would bring the app to its needs 
given the array of views. I have tested this with over 200 StyleViews with no side effects at all. That is not true that performance is compromised, at least not for me. The @swiftPunk arrayOfAnyView does not compile.

Comment: regarding "...initialize a structure with a string variable", 
honestly, typing `AnyView(Style1View())` instead of what you want to do `1 : "Style1View"`, 
is not going to break your back.

Comment: @workingdog: "I have tested this with over 200 StyleViews with no side effects at all. That is not true that performance is compromised, at least not for me." so you think if works well for 200 is good enough? I did not mean that it would get issue for 50 Views! I mentioned the comparing 2 kind of ways, first (the light) was is a dic, Second (the expensive) way is an array of AnyView! But if the OP change the single style views by time it would take lots of memory, and also it is deferent from Device to device if one device can handle the code easily it does not mean others will do the same.

Comment: there is nothing light with the dictionary, even it it could be constructed, 
don't know where that idea comes from.
And there is nothing heavy with an array. There is probably a better way to do this, 
but without knowing what the OP really is trying to achieve, this is simple 
and in keeping with what the OP wanted to do. 
Note that; `let arrayOfAnyView...map{}`  does not compile, and I'll be happy if you 
can show it working or any dictionary scheme. Regarding different devices, yeah good point.

Answer (score 0):

I think a much better way is to use a protocol which each of these conform to. You then only need to store the types, meaning it's really light-weight since you aren't instantiating a bunch of views that you may not need to use.

#### Example

Firstly, the `ContentView` so you can see mainly what's happening. It's an interactive example with a `Slider` so you can change the style to test it out.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private static let styleTypes: [StyledView.Type] = [
        StyleDefaultView.self,
        Style1View.self,
        Style2View.self,
        Style3View.self,
        Style4View.self
    ]

    @State private var currentStyle = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Style: \(currentStyle)")

            Slider(
                value: Binding<Double>(
                    get: { Double(currentStyle) },
                    set: { currentStyle = Int($0) }
                ),
                in: 0 ... 4,
                step: 1
            )

            Spacer()

            Self.styleTypes[currentStyle].init().buildView()
        }
    }
}
```

Result (with rest of code too):

[image: Result]

Protocol:

```
protocol StyledView {
    init()
    func buildView() -> AnyView
}

extension StyledView where Self: View {
    func buildView() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(self)
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is conform each view to `StyledView`, no need for extra code in each of those views. Example for first view (but do this for all of them):

```
struct StyleDefaultView: View, StyledView {
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("111")
        }
    }
}
```

*Side note: the `VStack` doesn't need those `()` after since you have a trailing closure.*